# OpenID Connect Authentication Successful. Now what?

Tags: c#, api, openid-connect, bearer-token

I'm writing a windows service in C# that needs to authenticate with an API and make some calls. I'm able to authenticate successfully with this API I'm talking to, but I can't seem to figure out how to use the response. The response looks like this:

```
{"access_token":"Es-Zjs_LI0tcXyLe3aEfgKPNLHN7CwyUhTss-cTld1A","expires_in":1800,"token_type":"Bearer","scope":"example","auth_state":1,"company":"examplecompany"}
```

I can get the access token out of that string if I want, but no matter how I pass it to a request, I get a 401 error. This is what my current iteration looks like:

```
    string results = "";
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",token);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://example.ca/endpoint"),
        //Headers =
        //{
        //    { "authorization", "Bearer"},
        //},
    };
    try
    {
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            results = body;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        results = "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
    }
    
    return results;
```

Where "token" is the string "Es-Zjs_LI0tcXyLe3aEfgKPNLHN7CwyUhTss-cTld1A" in this example. I had previously tried stitching the access_token value as a string to the "Bearer" string in the commented out section in the middle there. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to make a JwtSecurityToken out of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I understand it's largely situational depending on what API you're trying to connect to, for me the solution was to use this method to pass in the authentication token:

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = await daemonClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { MSGraphScope })
                                        .ExecuteAsync();
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
```

I've used the `authResult.AccessToken`. Not sure if it works in your scenario. The return type in my case was `Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult` type when I retrieved the token for a Graph API that I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the token you have received ("Es-Zjs_LI0tcXyLe3aEfgKPNLHN7CwyUhTss-cTld1A") is a reference token and not a JWT-token. Make sure your API accepts that type of token.

To use the token effectively in production then I would consider using the various helper methods found in the [IdentityModel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library and especially the [Worker application](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/worker.html#usage) helpers.